# Filtering out numbers when using ScalaNLP tokenizer

Tags: scala, nlp, tokenize, scala-nlp

is there a command in scala to ignore all kind of numbers, such as " IgnoreNumbers() ~> "?

I'm a scala newbie and, in fact, I only have to use one script in this language.

Thanks a lot for any help!

It's for a tokenizer from here http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/examples/example-1-dataset.scala:

```
val tokenizer = {
  SimpleEnglishTokenizer() ~>            // Remove punctuation
  CaseFolder() ~>                        // Lowercase everything
  WordsAndNumbersOnlyFilter() ~>         // Ignore non-words and non-numbers
  MinimumLengthFilter(3)                 // Take terms with >=3 characters
}
```

Comment: It's for a tokenizer, see above.

Comment: Ah, I saw that a regex pattern to ignore all numbers would also be possible. So, my question is: how can such a regex pattern look like?

Comment: It's about this example: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/examples/example-1-dataset.scala

Comment: Here, I should add a command to ignore all numbers

Comment: Sorry; i should have said this before.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ScalaNLP, but it looks like it is trivial to modify (or better, create a new type) based on [WordsAndNumbersOnlyFilter](https://github.com/scalanlp/chalk/blob/master/src/main/scala/chalk/text/transform/WordsAndNumbersOnlyFilter.scala) by simply removing the `Number` usage, e.g.

```
case class WordsOnlyFilter() extends Transformer {
  // original from WordsAndNumbersOnlyFilter
  // override def apply(terms : Iterable[String]) =
  //   terms.filter(term => TokenType.Word.matches(term) || TokenType.Number.matches(term));

  // Modification that doesn't use/accept TokenType.Number
  override def apply(terms : Iterable[String]) =
    terms.filter(term => TokenType.Word.matches(term));
}
```

Then:

```
val tokenizer = {
  // ..
  WordsOnlyFilter() ~>         // Ignore non-words
  // ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this proposition! :) I've got a stupid question: Where can / should I modify this? I used the tmt-0.4.0.jar, downloaded from here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/

Comment: @MarkF6 Just include it (WordsOnlyFilter) in your code. Make sure that the correct import statements (probably `chalk.text.transform`) are applied so that Transformer/TokenType.Word can be found.

Comment: Hm it gives me this error: "scalanlp.serialization.TypedCompanionException: No registered handler supports value type class Main$$anon$1$WordsOnlyFilter"

Comment: But I didn't add "import chalk.text.transform", because it could not be found :(

Comment: @MarkF6 Maybe that's not what the scalanlp library you have is using. In any case, simply find and modify/duplicate the `WordsAndNumbersOnlyFilter` filter class as a appropriate.